# "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date"

Tags: sql-server

este código es muy básico... ¿Me podrían ayudar?

```
create database Escuela

create table Maestros 
(
  usuario int not null,
  name varchar(50),
  country char(2),
  birthdate date
);

insert into Maestros values (1, 'Emmanuel', 'MX', 1996-07-23);
```

Me da un error de sintaxis

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está aquí, en el último parámetro:

```
insert into Maestros values (1, 'Emmanuel', 'MX', 1996-07-23);
```

en lugar de `1996-07-23` debe ser `'1996-07-23'`, fíjate en las comillas.  Sin las comillas sql interpretará esta fecha como un número, en específico intentará calcular 1996 - 7 - 23 = 1966.  Y ese es el mensaje de error que ves ahí, te indica que estás intentando asignar un número (`int`) a una fecha (`date`).